# What is the hidden state in prediction using RNN/LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Supposed that I have a time sequence from t = 0 to t = T, I want to use RNN/LSTM to train a model for future prediction purpose.

After training, when I make prediction at t = T+1, should I use the hidden state (and cell state if LSTM) at t = T to predict the output at t = T+1?

Supposed that I want to predict from t = T+1 to t = T+10, should I use the predicted y(T+1) as the input for next time step t = T+2? And use the predicted y(T+2) as the input for next time step t = T+3 so on and so forth?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should, generally the Hidden state is a vector or matrix that operates through all the sequence (time T). That is the main purpose of [RNN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g4aC.png), to compute its states by taking in count previous steps. You will feed your network for time T with your Hidden state (or LSTM cell) from previous steps (T-1) and your input as y(t-1).